# How to get a property from an object in typescript

Tags: angular, typescript

I have an object like this,from which i want to just fetch the "attributes" array and store into new variable.

```
obj =  {
        "_id": "5bf7e1be80c05307d06423c2",
        "agentId": "awais",
        "attributes": [ // that array.
            {
                "createdDate": "2018-11-23T11:17:18.771Z",
                "_id": "5bf7e1be80c05307d06423c4",
                "name": "Marketing",
                "description": "Arabic Language Attribute",
                "type": "Boolean",
                "value": "true",
                "usageCount": 0
            },
            {
                "createdDate": "2018-11-23T11:17:18.770Z",
                "_id": "5bf7e1be80c05307d06423c3",
                "name": "English",
                "description": "English Language Attribute",
                "type": "Proficiency",
                "value": "7",
                "usageCount": 0
            }
        ],
        "__v": 0
    }
```

Comment: So, what is your problem here?

Comment: I want to get the "attributes" array into new array variable, so that i can compare that array with another array.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure i got what you mean right, but if you want to access the object and get the array data, you can do it like this:

let's say your json object is saved in var "jsonObject", then you can get the array values like this:

```
var tempArray = jsonObject['attributes'];
```

Comment: this method not works i want to just fetch the "attributes" array from that object so that i can store that array into new variable and can match it with other arrays